# Costs generated by old versions of my appengine application

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have many versions of appengine instances that are active but not used because they are old. What are the costs they can generate? How do you behave with the old versions of appengine instances? Do you delete them or deactivate them?

On the documentation I don't find any reference to the costs of the old instances.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing?hl=it

UPDATE:
(GAE STANDARD)

Thank you

[image]

Comment: GAE standard or flex?

Comment: GAE Standard...

Answer (score 2):

It's a poorly documented aspect of App Engine. What you describe as versions that are "not used" are more specifically versions that don't receive traffic. But depending on your scaling configuration (essentially defined in your app.yaml file), there may not be a 1:1 relationship between traffic and the number of active instances serving a version.

For example, I'm familiar with using "automatic_scaling" with min_instances = 1. This will prevent a service to scale to zero instance and have latency to serve an incoming request after some idle time, but it also means that any version until deleted will generate a baseline cost of 1 instance running 24/7.

Also, I've found that the estimated number of instances displayed in the dashboard you screenshotted can be misleading (more specifically, it can show 0 instance while there is actually one running).

Note that if you do not have scaling related configuration in your app.yaml file, you should check what are the default values currently considered by App Engine.

It's tricky when you get started and I'm sure I'm not the only one who lost most of the free trial budget because of this.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a limit of versions you can have depending on your [app's pricing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/an-overview-of-app-engine#limits):

| Limit | Free app | Paid app |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Max versions | 15 | 210 |

It seems that you can have them active in case you want to switch between versions [migrating](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrating-traffic) or [splitting](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/splitting-traffic) the traffic between them, but they won't charge you for them if you don't reach more than 15 versions.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is (at the time of writing) unclear as to what the costs are for versions or services with no instances running.

Looking at some active projects it seems that there are storage charges associated with the artifacts that GAE uses – this looks to include some costs from inactive versions -- but not as much as you might think as at a quick glance it doesn't look like the whole of each version is stored independently, rather just the diffs or similar.